# Run same python code in two terminals, will them interfere each other?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a python script which takes a while to finish its executing depending on the passed argument. So if I run them from two terminals with different arguments, do they get their own version of the code? I can't see two `.pyc` files being generated.

Terminal 1 runs: `python prog.py 1000 > out_1000.out`

Before the script running on terminal 1 terminate, i start running an another; thus terminal 2 runs:  `python prog.py 100 > out_100.out`

Or basically my question is could they interfere with each other?

Comment: What do you mean by 'overwrite each other'?

Comment: `a.out` would get overwritten with the latest run, use `>>` instead of `>`, `python prog.py` would run just fine on both terminals

Comment: `a.out`? I see no C here.

Comment: A `.pyc` file is generated when the file gets imported. But it is in general save to run the same python script again while it is already running. For each script a own python process is created where the script gets executed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are writing the output to the same file in disk, then yes, it will be overwritten. However, it seems that you're actually printing to the stdout and then redirect it to a file. So that is not the case here.

Now answer to your question is simple: there is no interaction between two different executions of the same code. When you execute a program or a script OS will load the code to the memory and execute it and subsequent changes to code has nothing to do with the code that is already running. Technically a program that is running is called a process. Also when you run a code on two different terminals there will be two different processes on the OS one for each of them and there is no way for two process to interfere unless you explicitly do that (IPC or inter-process communication) which you are doing here.

So in summary you can run your code simultaneously on different terminals they will be completely independent.

Comment: +1 liked the way how you answered the question with basic operating systems, mem/process management concepts. thanks!

Comment: Good and neat explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Each Python interpreter process is independent. How the script reacts to itself being run multiple times depends on the exact code in use, but *in general* they should not interfere.

Answer (score 0):

1. .pyc file reference http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-create-a-pyc-file.htm

> Python automatically compiles your script to compiled code, so called
>   byte code, before running it. When a module is imported for the first
>   time, or when the source is more recent than the current compiled
>   file, a .pyc file containing the compiled code will usually be created
>   in the same directory as the .py file.

2. If you afraid your code get overwritten due to whatever mistake, you should learn to put your code under VERSION CONTROL. Register github and use git to do that.
3. bigger sign ">" will send the output to the right handler. It you specify file name, it will push the output to that file name.  Even in different terminal, if you run the code inside the same folder, use the ">" point to SAME file name, the file on the right of the ">" definitely get overwrite.
4. Program SOURCE CODE ARE NOT mutable during execution. Unless you acquire high level program hacking skill.
5. Each program will run inside its  "execution workspace". Unless you make a code that tap into **same resources**(like change same file,shared reources ), otherwise there is no interference. (except if one exhaust all CPU, Memory resources,  the second one will be interfere, but that is other story)